# Using bracket notation opposed to eval

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
var module = function(){
    console.log('module ran')
}

var someString = 'module'

[string]() //TypeError: object is not a function

eval(someString)() // works fine!
```

I'm trying to run the module function, of course I don't want to use eval but, I don't see why brackets isn't work.

**How should this be written to get the same result at the eval**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bracket notation is used to access object properties. If that's on the global scope (and if you're on a browser), you can use this:

```
window[someString]();
```

Comment: This works perfect for my example but, not so much for my actual case (too much to post). I'm using requirejs and the function is a amd param in the case. Should this sill apply? the variable don't seem to be in the window obj.

Comment: It's not in window in that case. And it's not part of an object. You can either manually create an object with each argument as a property, or use eval.

Comment: I was trying to get around doing both but, I guess it's needed in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @delboud Just a last, perhaps better, option: since it's a function argument, you can access it by index in the arguments object, ie: `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]` etc.

Comment: @bfavertto—it seems that the value being passed is a string that is the name of the function, not a reference to the function, otherwise *eval* would not work either.

Comment: @RobG The function reference is passed as an argument, and there's *also* a string with its name (not sure where that one comes from). At least that's what I understood.